# Question about complex differentiability (what is the difference between these two propositions)

Tags: complex-analysis

My Question is regarding the following Propositions:

**Proposition 1**:
The following statements about a function $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ are equivalent

i) $f$ is complex differentiable in $z_0 \in D$

ii) $f$ is real differentiable in $z_0$ and the Cauchy Riemann equations hold.

**Proposition 2** (Sufficient condition for complex differentiability):

Let $u,v$ be continuously differentiale real functions, then $f:=u+iv$ is real differentiable in every point in $D$.
If additionally the Cauchy Riemann equations hold, then $f$ is complex differentiable in $D$.

Arguing from Proposition 1,ii:

If $f$ is real differentiable in all points in $D$ and also the Cauchy Riemann equations hold for all points in $D$, then this should mean that $f$ is complex differentiable for every point in $D$.

Question: Why do I even need **Proposition 2**?

The only new thing that Proposition 2 states is that if $u,v$ are continuously differentiable real functions, then $f:=u+iv$ is real differentiable. (But this was obvious from real analysis in $R^n$)

Is there something I don't see?

Comment: Depending on your setup, 2 may be easier to prove than 1, and intro complex analysis books often try not to assume the reader remembers much multivariable calculus. I'm not sure if this addresses your question/would count as an answer or not.

Comment: @MarkS. Thank you!

Comment: Yes the only thing new in proposition 2 is that continuously differentiable implies real differentiable, which, as you noted, is a theorem from real analysis (the proof involves the mean value theorem).